# Concatenar resultados de ultimo numFile(id) registrado y otro actualizar campo

Tags: php, sql, condiciones, insert, update

Necesito saber como concatenar resultados obtenidos despues de un `insert` y actualizar un campo, con la información...El insert, los isset y demas funciona correctamente, todo lo que quiero hacer esta despues de `if ($result > 0)` .

En `$query2` estoy obteniendo `c.cat_name` , `sc.idSub`  y `numFile` pero solo del ultimo `numFile`(id autoincrement) que fue registrado.

En el query `$newNumPart` quisiera actualizar el campo `id_item` con los `3` datos resultantes del primer `query`, añadiendo información nueva y agregando `"00"` y `"-"` a ciertos campos.

Ejemplo:

Mi ultimo `numfile`(id) fue `4`, obtengo `c.cat_name`,`sc.idSub`,`numFile` que podría ser igual a `PRO` ,`6` Y `4` (ultimo id registrado), y quisiera que el campo `id_item` se actualizara y quedara de la siguiente manera con los datos anteriores.

**`id_item =  PRO-006-004`**

```
else if(isset($_POST['description_item']) && isset($_POST['price_item'])
        && isset($_POST['manufacturer']) && isset($_POST['model_item']) && isset($_POST['reorder_Level'])
        && isset($_POST['target_Stock']) && isset($_POST['imageName']) && isset($_POST['commentt'])
        && isset($_POST['fkEngineer']) && isset($_POST['fkCategory']) && isset($_POST['fkLocation'])
        && isset($_POST['fkSupplier']) && isset($_POST['fkUnit'])&& isset($_POST['fkSubCat']))
    {
            $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();

            date_default_timezone_set('America/Tijuana');
            $hoy = date("Y-m-d");
            $year = date("y");

            $query = 'INSERT INTO inventory_list (description_item,price_item,manufacturer,model_item,
            reorder_Level,target_Stock,image,registerDate,commentt,fkEngineer,fkCategory,fkLocation,fkSupplier,fkUnit,fkSubCat)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);';

                $result = $connection->executeNonQuery($query,array($_POST['description_item'], $_POST['price_item'] ,
                $_POST['manufacturer'], $_POST['model_item'], $_POST['reorder_Level'], $_POST['target_Stock'], $_POST['imageName'],
                $hoy, $_POST['commentt'] ,$_POST['fkEngineer'],$_POST['fkCategory'],$_POST['fkLocation'],$_POST['fkSupplier'],$_POST['fkUnit'],$_POST['fkSubCat']));


                if ($result > 0)
                {

        //Obtengo el ultimo numfile (id) registrado
            $query2= "SELECT c.cat_name,sc.idSub,numFile FROM inventory_list
            INNER JOIN category AS c ON id_category=fkCategory
            INNER JOIN sub_category AS sc ON idSub=fkSubCat where numFile ORDER BY numFile desc LIMIT 1";    

        //Esto es correcto?
            $getNumPart = $connection->executeNonQuery($query2,array($_POST['numFile']));


        //Como concateno los resultados y actualizar el campo id_item?
            $newNumPart ='UPDATE inventory_list set id_item = ?';
            $saveNumPart = $connection->executeNonQuery($newNumPart,array($_POST['cat_name'],$_POST['idSub'],$_POST['numFile']));

        echo json_encode(array(
                        'status' => '0',
                        'errorMessage' => 'ITEM registrado'
                    ));
}
```

El problema que tengo es que no se como concatenar los datos y donde hago eso, alguien que me pueda ayudar, se lo agradeceria.

Comment: Para concatenar en php se usa `.` y no `+`

Comment: y cual seria el problema?

Comment: Pregunta editada.

Comment: Tienes un código rarísimo, que concatena dentro de un array: `array($_POST['cat_name'].'-'.'00'.$_POST['idSub'].'-'.'00'.$_POST['numFile'])`, ¿por qué haces eso? Deberías hacerlo al revés: obtener los datos primero y luego crear el array si fuera preciso. Además parece que deberían ir dos valores en el array, no uno (el `UPDATE` tiene dos marcadores `?`)... Y si tienes dudas sobre los resultados que estás obteniendo, ¿por qué no los pruebas y sales de dudas? Tampoco verificas con `isset` o `empty` lo que hay en `$_POST`

Comment: En mi pregunta especifique que no sabia si estaba concatenando de la manera correcta, ahora se que esta mal hacerlo de esa manera,igual gracias. Respecto a lo del isset o empty, el codigo que puse solo es lo relevante al problema que tengo, antes de eso se hace el respectivo insert de datos que se capturan en un formulario, esto es la continuacion despues de que todo fue registrado correctamente.